# Stackauth.com has certificate issued for *.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, security

The usual decision when the host name and the name in the certificate don't match is to reject the certificate. I see no reason to desensitize users to Man-in-the-Middle attacks by telling them: "it's okay to accept a certificate although the names don't match".

EDIT:

I have Firefox Cert Patrol extension installed. Yes, I have read the alt names, but not everybody does that. Scaring a user away out of desire to save money on certs isn't a good tactic, IMHO.

EDIT #2: As reported by Carlos Campderrós (and observed by me now), the name mismatch is definitely encountered without any alternative names on https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the motivation behind this isn't saving money :)

Comment: If cert is OK (and it is), then it is faulty extension that scares users, not Stack Exchange. Tell them it's unfair. I mean, really, you should post a bugreport.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug of a Firefox extension. 

Comment: BTW the certificate on https://stackoverflow.com/ is invalid for my firefox 24.0 (on Fedora 19), with only Firebug, WebDeveloper toolbar and eventbug installed as addons. Examining the certificate it shows the altNames: `*.stackexchange.com stackexchange.com` only. The same happens with Google Chrome 29.0.1547.76

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós - something weird goes on; the same here.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós remember, SSL is not an officially supported feature yet (as far as I know). Your milage may vary. Just because its available doesn't mean it will always work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the subject alternative names on the certificate that is issued to Stack Exchange:

```
DNS Name=*.stackexchange.com
DNS Name=stackexchange.com
DNS Name=meta.stackexchange.com
DNS Name=*.meta.stackexchange.com
DNS Name=*.stackoverflow.com
DNS Name=stackoverflow.com
DNS Name=serverfault.com
DNS Name=stackauth.com
DNS Name=sstatic.net
DNS Name=meta.serverfault.com
DNS Name=superuser.com
DNS Name=meta.superuser.com
DNS Name=stackapps.com
DNS Name=openid.stackauth.com
```

All of these domains would be valid SSL certificate domains. stackapps.com is one of the accepted domains, and you shouldn't be getting a certificate warning for visiting https://stackauth.com.

Comment: I do get a warning - I have Firefox Cert Patrol extension installed. Yes, I have read the alt names, but not everybody does that. Scaring a user away out of desire to save money on certs isn't a good tactic, IMHO.

Comment: @DeerHunter I'm not speaking for the admins here. I have a feeling the extension will land in the "unsupported" realm. It works in the [supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/215013) for me.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: @DeerHunter For what it's worth, it sounds like you found a bug (or feature request?) for the Firefox extension. Having that field displayed to the end user in certain circumstances, like this one, seems like a good idea.

Comment: @DeerHunter this wasn't a money saving decision at all, it's consolidation of certificates given IPv4 address space availability and how our load balancer architecture is laid out.  Compared to standard certificates, it's actually quite a pain in the ass to update this certificate since it involves manual intervention by our CA and is not self-serve.